# selenium not finding webdrivers

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The problem is simple: I have a project with two python files (main.py and create.py) and a folder called webdrivers with the webdrivers for chrome firefox and msedge so that I can ask the user which browser they want selenium to use.
in the create.py I have this code:

```
def create_remote():
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./webdrivers/chromedriver.exe") 
    driver.get("https://github.com/login")

if __name__=='__main__':
    create_remote()
```

If I just run the create.py it works no problem but if I call the 'create_remote()' function in the main.py it says that the chromedriver.exe needs to be in path.
Any help?

Comment: Quick question is your chrome_directory correct?

Comment: it's the default chrome installation directory

Comment: What does `where chromedriver.exe` report when running that command in a normal Windows command prompt?

Comment: Also, what is your current working directory when running your python script?

Comment: Also, what @Philip is asking is *not* which directory Google Chrome is installed at. Which directory is *ChromeDriver* installed at?

Comment: Try pasting in the full path of your web driver. Also, uninstall Chrome, then reinstall it. if that doesn't work, try updating both the driver and the web driver.

Comment: @Simon sorry for being inactive suddenly.  I think you might have not installed the ChromeDriver. I'd recommend you download it from this link: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads select the chrome driver version depending on your chrome_version. After the download, copy the path where *chrome driver* was installed in. Then paste that path in the line of code which tells Selenium where Chrome Driver is installed.

Comment: Let me know if it works :)

Comment: I actually also tried to isntall it using chocolatey but nothing worked. The only thing I could do was place the webdriver files into the same directory as the main.py file and it worked. Still no idea how tho.